# Compass backgroud-image background-color?

Tags: css, compass-sass

Don't know how to apply background-image and background-color to div using Compass 
 tried this way

```
 @include background(
                  image-url($bg-sprite) no-repeat,
                  color (#333));
```

made this way :))))

```
@include background(
                      image-url($bg-sprite) no-repeat,
                      linear-gradient(#333, #333));
```

Is there better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about Compass here.  The background mixin is supposed to take valid background declarations as its arguments:

```
.foo {
    @include background(image-url($bg-sprite) no-repeat #333);
}
```

However, if you aren't using a gradient, there's no need to use the mixin at all:

```
.foo {
    background: image-url($bg-sprite) no-repeat #333;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer (for your other questions, too!).